# Rename database files: drop tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I would like to rename database files (.mdf ja .ldf) in SQL Server. Do I have to drop all tables from the database before that?

Comment: Why do you want to change away from the default?  If someone has access, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Becaus I want to rename the database itself, and also the database files.

Comment: Yeap, I always do this so that it is obvious to all what the file (whether on disk or backup tape, etc) is about.  I find that with a dozen or so DBs there's no real problems with the default names but it soon gets difficult if its a large site with Prod DBs restored as test instances, etc it soon gets hard to remember that prod_db_log is from test_db, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

To rename database and files..

- [detach databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx)
- rename files
- attach with another name

Answer (score 0):

No, Just Right click the Database name and choose Rename.

Comment: No this only changes the LOGICAL NAME in the Database, the files in the background do not get changed.